# Unable to make Firebase work for a non Gradle build: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: android, firebase, initialization, firebase-analytics

The app I am working on has a very customized build process. It's not possible to use gradle to build my app. It's not ideal, but I cannot change anything about it.
Nevertheless, I want to use Firebase Analytics in my app. In included the modules firebase-core, firebase-common, firebase-analytics, firebase-analytics-impl, firebase-iid, firebase-iid-interop, firebase-measurement-connector, firebase-measurement-connector-imple, play-services-measurement-base and play-services-measurement-api. I also added the following strings to my `strings.xml`, with the values I found in the `google-services.json` for my Firebase project:

```
<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">xxx</string>
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">xxx</string>
<string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">xxx</string>
<string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">xxx</string>
<string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">xxx</string>
<string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">xxx</string>
<string name="project_id" translatable="false">xxx</string>
```

(as described [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/how-does-firebase-initialize-on-android.html)) and removed the `FirebaseInitProvider` from the AndroidManifest.
In my apps `Application` class `onCreate()` I do:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId(getString(R.string.google_app_id))
            .setApiKey(getString(R.string.google_api_key));
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build(), "[DEFAULT]");
```

No issues so far. When the above code is executed, I get a debug log message saying:

```
FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
```

All good, I didn't include the auth module. I don't need it for my app. When I call `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(adblockSettingsTextView.getContext()).getFirebaseInstanceId()` it returns a String value, so I assume the initialization was successful.

Now every time I want to log an event like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Dashboard");
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

I see the an error in my log saying `Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.` On top of that, I don't see any active users in the Firebase Analytics dashboard.

I read all documents I could find and tried my best to find the cause for this problem. But right now I have no more ideas what I can check or change to make it work. Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? Possibly by now they may have solved this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case someone else runs into the same issue, I leave the answer I got from the Firebase Support here:

> Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) doesn't support dynamic
>   initialization. Our engineers are checking the possible solutions to
>   support this. It's just that we still haven't found a definite
>   timeline as to when (or if) this will be available.
>
> GA4F will not work without the google-services.json file (or Gradle on
>   your end). Even though you can initialize the FirebaseApp dynamically
>   through code, GA4F will not recognize this and will only result in the
>   error message you are seeing. The scenario you are getting is only
>   specific to Google Analytics for Firebase. However, you can still use
>   other products like Firestore, Realtime  Database, Storage even if you
>   are not using Gradle plugin.