# Firebase Google Analytics with custom FirebaseOptions initilaize method

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have to add simple Firebase Google Analytics for my android application.

**I need to select my app's Firebase project at runtime.**

*"It's very rare, but sometimes an app must be able to select its Firebase project at runtime. This means your app can't use the automatic init provided by the FirebaseInitProvider that's merged into your app. In that case, the solution has two tasks."*

Link for reference : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

So, In my case I have done as below :

1. Created an Application class :

   ```
   public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApplicationId("1:5478125639014:android:054aa87g102b94aa5").setApiKey("ABcdXyzpQrst_8tlItnC5rcbgxkK_PqrstGWsTKo");
           FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
       }
   ```
2. Added required manifest Internet permissions.
3. Added dependencies :

   **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0'**

Issue is I can't see any analytics data there and Application is not getting connected in Google Analytic's final step.

What might be issue or something pending there?

Comment: did you add `google-services.json` file to your project? if yes then please look into the Logcat. you will find some logs regarding the issue with firebase.

Comment: @Jaymin For doing manually we don't need to add google-services.json file. We can do it manually using FirebaseOptions as it is explained here : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html Please check and try to understand.   NOTE : I can do analytics in normal way with the use of google-services.json file and plugin.

Comment: @JaiminModi I'm using multiple flavor, can I use different api key for each flavor?

Comment: This is the main reason to change firebase analytics to another service. In other case this is insecure to publish keys in xml. And third-party developer is able to extract firebase keys and reuse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the point explained here : [Unable to make Firebase work for a non Gradle build: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927957/unable-to-make-firebase-work-for-a-non-gradle-build-missing-google-app-id-fire/55006495#55006495)  (Different Question)

> Google Analytics for Firebase (GA4F) doesn't support dynamic
>   initialization. Our engineers are checking the possible solutions to
>   support this. It's just that we still haven't found a definite
>   timeline as to when (or if) this will be available.
>
> GA4F will not work without the google-services.json file (or Gradle on your end). Even though you can initialize the FirebaseApp
>   dynamically through code, GA4F will not recognize this and will only
>   result in the error message you are seeing. The scenario you are
>   getting is only specific to Google Analytics for Firebase. However,
>   you can still use other products like Firestore, Realtime Database,
>   Storage even if you are not using Gradle plugin.

**Finally, Done it in below way :**

**What I needed to do :**

1. From One Google account, Notification should work.
2. Have to use **separate(another)** Google account for Google Analytics. (Read the question. You will get the Idea.)

**What I have done :**

1. Integrated Push Notification task using FirebaseOptions by considering it as secondary app as below :

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setApplicationId("1:4578412596352:b47d85se5v2z1a2b").setApiKey("AI4f896IG11gFh5R452FdiYau27sdA7IQ85EdY1").setProjectId("mycuteapp-57490").setGcmSenderId("547841025698").build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), options,"pushNotifications");

2. For the Google Analytics, Done it in a common way i.e. using google-services.json file.

In Short, Currently guidance from this Official link **is not working in case of Google Analytics**: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

Comment: Avoid to share you personal project info like APIs keys in stackoverflow question and answers.

Comment: @pRaNaY Thanks Sir, I have already posted by changing it with random values. Modi is here :)

Comment: Great to know it is random values. and I am not a sir.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is not the answer you were expecting but the sad reality is that **you can't dynamically initialize your Firebase Analytics**.

In official Firebase repository you can see issue https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/769 and there the official answer is "this is currently working as intended, the Analytics SDK does not allow configuration of the App ID at runtime". I don't believe it changed since then.

I know that these posts may sound confusing in that context:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

But intended use case is having different `FirebaseApp` configuration (for different databases, for example) and **not** different `FirebaseAnalytics` configuration. And Firebase Analytics is just one of many products under Firebase.

So you don't need to use gradle plugin, but you still need to have String resource called `google_app_id` that contains your Firebase App Id and **only that will be used to configure FirebaseAnalytics.**

It doesn't mean that dynamic initialization of FirebaseAnalytics can't be done at all, but it would require reverse engineering, hacky solution and it would be fragile - in short, probably not a good idea.

I'm not sure what is your use case but if you only want to **delay Firebase Analytics initilization**, you could consider disabling it at the beginning: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=android

Comment: But, Same thing is working in IOS..!!! Then, Why there's issue in Android...!!! My Partner can simply initialize as many firebase projects as he wants in single app and using same way as I have explained in above question.

Comment: Hello Sir, Can you please explain your point : "you still need to have String resource called google_app_id that contains your Firebase App Id" ? Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: If you don't want to use plugin, then you have to do some things manually, that would be usually done by plugin. And one of these things is adding `google_app_id` as string resource. So you can do that manually by adding `google_app_id` to your strings.xml. And `google_app_id` is your Firebase App Id, e.g. "1:4578412596352:android:b47d85se5v2z1a2b". I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: Delaying initialization is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!