# Initializing Firebase at Runtime for Analytics logEvents not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I have an app that needs 2 Firebase projects. Depending on the login option used, i need to `logEvents` to a specific Firebase project.

I cannot use multiple `google-services.json` in different directories based on build variant/flavor because it needs to be one app. As such, i

1. Deleted `google-services.json` from the project
2. commented `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in gradle
3. Initialized Firebase with below code using values from `google-services.json` file

   ```
    val firebaseOptions = Builder()
           .setApplicationId("client.client_info.mobilesdk_app_id")
           .setApiKey("client.client_info.current_key")
           .setDatabaseUrl("project_info.firebase_url")
           .setGcmSenderId("project_info.project_number")
           .setStorageBucket("project_info.storage_bucket")
           .setProjectId("project_info.project_id")
           .build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, firebaseOptions, "[DEFAULT]")
   ```

I'm getting below error though.

```
E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
E/FA: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

Is there a way to solve this issue? I need to initialize Firebase at runtime after a user action and logEvents to Firebase

Comment: From the code you have provided, I see nothing wrong. Can you place a little bit more of code to see how you are fetching the arguments passed to the builder? Specially the applicationId

Comment: @SergioPardo i have updated the question to see origin of builder arguments

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible, I dig around a little bit more, and the experience you are getting is the expected behavior: ***Analytics does not work with builder (custom) initialization***.

You can check a statement from the firebase support team here: [Unable to make Firebase work for a non Gradle build: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927957/unable-to-make-firebase-work-for-a-non-gradle-build-missing-google-app-id-fire/55006495#55006495)

Yet, I discovered this two workarounds on a thread on GitHub, but they do not apply to your use case since it's done at compilation time.

Workaround:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/66#issuecomment-697341745
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/66#issuecomment-755434814

I suggest you to move your analytics to another provider in case this is a stopper for you, or just leave analytics on a single project and add an attribute to differentiate between user/flows.